# SQLite3 record manipulation

Tags: python, database, sqlite, data-manipulation

I am making a login system in Python using SQLite3. My code selects all records where the username and password stored in the database is met as follows.

```
c.execute('SELECT * from foo WHERE username="%s" AND password="%s"' (username, password).
if c.fetchone is not None:
    do stuff
```

I am unaware of how to then assign the data from that record into a local variable inside a function, so I can check it's value. In this case, I want to retrieve the usergroup value from the record I just searched for, then check if it is 1 or 2, to determine which function to call next.

Comment: `fetchone` is a method; you call it, and it returns the data.

Comment: Then how do I use `fetchone` in that way?

Comment: Just like any other method. `data = c.fetchone()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the `fetchone` method, you must use parentheses:

```
if c.fetchone() is not None:
```

And if you do not assign `fetchone()`'s return value to a variable, it is lost.

It would be a better idea to iterate directly over the cursor:

```
for row in c:
    print('value in first column: ', row[0])
    break
else:
    print('not found')
```

And you should SELECT only a single column, which makes accessing its value easier:

```
c.execute('SELECT usergroup FROM ...')
for (usergroup,) in c:
    print('group: ', usergroup)
```

And if somebody enters the password `" OR "1"="1`, then he gets in anyway. To prevent such [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), always use parameters:

```
c.execute('SELECT usergroup FROM foo WHERE username=? AND password=?',
          (username, password))
for (usergroup,) in c:
    print('group: ', usergroup)
    break
else:
    print('not found')
```